# Show that the graph $\{{(x,y) \in \mathbb{R}^2: y=\cos x}\}$ is closed in the metric space $\mathbb{R}^2$

Tags: general-topology

Question: 
Show that the graph $\{{(x,y) \in  \mathbb{R}^2: y=\cos x}\}$ is closed in the metric space $\mathbb{R}^2$

Proof:

Let $f(x)=y=\cos x$, then $f$ is continuous.  Since $f$ is continuous, we show that the image of $f$ is closed, then that implies that the pre-image is also closed.  But we know $-1\leq f(x) \leq 1$  for any $x \in \mathbb{R}$, therefore $f(x)$ is closed.

-- I am pretty much stuck here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider  $g(x,y) = y-\cos x$ defined as a function $\mathbf{R}^2\to \mathbf{R}$. This is a continuous function. SO the pre-image of the singleton $\{0\}$ is a closed set. The pre-image is precisely the graph. This works for any continuous function, not necessarily the cosine function.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this by showing that the set $\{(x,y) : y = \cos x\}$ contains all its limit points. Let $\{(x_n,y_n)\}_{n=1}^{\infty}$ be a sequence converging to $(x,y)$ such that $y_n = \cos (x_n)$. Then $\{x_n\}_{n=1}^{\infty}$ converges to $x$ and $\{y_n\}_{n=1}^{\infty}$ converges to $y$. Using this and continuity of cosine we get
$$y = \lim_{n \to \infty}y_n = \lim_{n \to \infty}\cos(x_n) = \cos(\lim_{n \to \infty}x_n) = \cos x.$$

Answer (score 0):

Consider the set $\mathbb {R}^2-\{{(x,y) \in  \mathbb{R}^2: y=\cos x}\}$ this set is clearly open. You can always find a ball of the center $(x,y)$ and radius $\epsilon$: $\mathbb {B((x,y),\epsilon )}$